# Auto Copying multiple images and show tile notifications?

Tags: c#, windows-8

This is my code for Windows 8 metro apps, in which I copy 1 image from the local folder to my app storage folder and then it shows a tile notification. Please help me to auto copy all images from Picture Library and then these images shown in tile notifications.
i don't know how to access or copy all images from Picture Library... no user interface for copy images.

public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
    {
        string imageRelativePath = String.Empty;

```
    public BlankPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        CopyImages();
    }

    public async void CopyImages()
    {

        FileOpenPicker picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        picker.CommitButtonText = "Copy";
        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        StorageFile newFile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(file.Name);
        await file.CopyAndReplaceAsync(newFile);
        this.imageRelativePath = newFile.Path.Substring(newFile.Path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

                IWideTileNotificationContent tileContent = null;
                ITileWideImage wideContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWideImage();
                wideContent.RequireSquareContent = false;
                wideContent.Image.Src = "ms-appdata:///local/" + this.imageRelativePath;
                wideContent.Image.Alt = "App data";
                tileContent = wideContent;
                tileContent.RequireSquareContent = false;
                TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileContent.CreateNotification());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

1st give the path of images folder and then make a list of these images through  IReadOnlyList, and set loop on copy images to end, after that just set timer on TileUpdateManager. and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

to enumerate files in PicturesLibrary:

```
// from my sample app "MetroContractSample" http://metrocontractsample.codeplex.com/documentation
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, new[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif", }) { FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep, };
StorageFileQueryResult query = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
var fileInfoFactory = new FileInformationFactory(query, ThumbnailMode.SingleItem);
IReadOnlyList<FileInformation> fileInfoList = await fileInfoFactory.GetFilesAsync();
```

NOTE: You have to declare the Capability for PicturesLibrary in Package.appxmanifest.